# Why do multiple requests to ServiceStack http handlers fail?

Tags: servicestack

I've verified this behavior with multiple projects, including the Windows Service AppHost Starter Template example project (unmodified). Initial requests succeed and display the default TODO page, but subsequent requests never complete.

It's simple to reproduce this scenario. Just perform the first request to http://localhost:83. You'll see the default TODO page render fine. Now hit "refresh" in the browser and you should now see the request never come through. If running in debug mode through VS, you'll see ObjectDisposedExceptions in the Output window.

Is there a problem with the latest ServiceStack codebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an issue in the response stream not being closed properly.

Should now be fixed in the latest version. Can you try again with the latest version v3.07, either on:

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/downloads

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/downloads

or 'ServiceStack' on NuGet.

Comment: Very fast action! I've verified 3.0.7 does not exhibit the issue. Thanks!

Comment: @Kilhoffer Glad to hear it's sorted. That's the beauty of running on a OSS engine in full swing :)